# What's the difference between Doorbell and Doorbell Record?

Tags: networking, infiniband, rdma

I'm new to RDMA technology and I can't figure out what's the difference between doorbell and doorbell record. In my opinion, when Software posts its work request, it rings the doorbell register to notify the hardware to fetch the work request. I don't know why there is doorbell record and how it works, any suggestion or reference is well-appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Doorbell Records are just structures of one more Doorbells. At the low level, if you place a Work Queue Entry into a Work Queue, you need to "Ring the Doorbell" to let the Hardware know that it can fetch an entry. At the higher level, at the Verbs level, you generally do not need to interact with the Doorbells. When you do a ibv_post_send() you have no need to interact with the Doorbells. The ibv_post_send() implementation takes care of handling this.